# Помогите решить проблему с выведением записей с метками в Wordpress

Tags: php, массивы, wordpress, циклы

С помощью этого кода

```
<?php                   
$terms = get_terms( array(
    'taxonomy'      => array( 'post_tag' ), // название таксономии с WP 4.5
    'orderby'       => 'id', 
    'order'         => 'ASC',
    'hide_empty'    => true, 
    'object_ids'    => null,
    'include'       => array(),
    'exclude'       => array(), 
    'exclude_tree'  => array(), 
    'number'        => '', 
    'fields'        => 'all', 
    'count'         => false,
    'slug'          => '', 
    'parent'         => '',
    'hierarchical'  => true, 
    'child_of'      => 0, 
    'get'           => '', // ставим all чтобы получить все термины
    'name__like'    => '',
    'pad_counts'    => false, 
    'offset'        => '', 
    'search'        => '', 
    'cache_domain'  => 'core',
    'name'          => 'блог_метка',    // str/arr поле name для получения термина по нему. C 4.2.
    'childless'     => false, // true не получит (пропустит) термины у которых есть дочерние термины. C 4.2.
) );


echo '<pre>';
foreach( $terms as $term ){
    print_r($term);
}
echo '</pre>';

?>
```

выводится такой объект

```
[term_id] => 133
[name] => блог_метка
[slug] => metka_blog
[term_group] => 0
[term_taxonomy_id] => 133
[taxonomy] => post_tag
[description] => 
[parent] => 0
[count] => 3
[filter] => raw
```

Как мне вывести эти 3 записи в цикле?

Comment: В чем собственно вопрос?  echo $term->name и т.д.

Comment: @Krya этот код выводит название метки - блог_метка . А как мне вывести записи в цикле( [count] => 3 ) - их сейчас 3 штуки, чтобы только они отображались на экране ?

Comment: Тебе нужны все посты от этих меток?

Comment: @Krya, да ! именно! в цикле их вывести на экране)

Answer (score 1):

Для вывода постов из меток нужно использовать в WP_Query параметр tax_query Подробнее: https://wp-kama.ru/function/wp_query. Пример:

```
$query = new WP_Query( [
    'post_type'      => 'post',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'tax_query'      => [
        [
            'taxonomy' => 'post_tag',
            'field'    => 'ids',
            'terms'    => [ 10, 20, 30 ] // ID's your tags
        ]
    ]
] );

if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
    while( $query->have_posts() ) {
        $query->the_post();
        the_title();
    }
} );
wp_reset_postdata();
```

Comment: спасибо, есть продвижение... с помощью такого кода получил все объекты, что нужно. А какие свойства есть у объекта, как их посмотреть?

Comment: подскажите, что делаю не так... С помощью этого кода выводит только 1 пост...не знаю почему

if ( $query_new->have_posts() ) {
     $query_new->the_post();
     ?>
            <div class="col-md-6">
          <div class="blog-card">
           <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="blog-title"> <?php the_title(); ?> </a>
           <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail('sidebar-preview'); ?></a>
           <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
          </div>
         </div>
 <?php
 }

Comment: @ОлексійСлєпцов поправил)